# Ribbon "Page" tab is missing in Modern UI Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, publishing-page, modern-experience, site-level-ribbon

I need help. I didn't create this specific site so I had no clue what the person did and probably didn't know what he was doing. So it appears that turned on a publishing feature and the page relies a lot on the modern look of Sharepoint. I have no problems with that, however I would have approached creating the site differently. But since he already gone far enough, I decided to work with it. Since recently he left the company, we haven't had any issue of the current users accessing the page. Now that we hired 2 new users, I added them in the Sharepoint group but on the main home page it gave them an Access Denied and must send a request. So I figured maybe the "Page Permissions" needed to be modified because it was unique... and that's where I am stuck... in the classic UI, there is a ribbon "Page" tab.. this does not show anywhere in the Modern UI. However on my other sites that has a Modern UI, they all show up fine. So I am stuck to where I can at least give 2 new hires to have access on the Home/Front Page when they have access into the site already.

here is the screenshot of having the no "Page" tab.
[image: No Page ribbon anywhere I click and even Edit mode.]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there is custom permissions on that specific page? You should be able to see the item through either Site Content or through Site Settings - > permissions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to read. Yes, that's the first thing I always check and do. As you had mentioned about "that specific page" (aka Page Permission)... that's exactly I am looking for but it is none existent in the modern ui :( .... So here is what I did so far on the new modern UI... I went into Site Contents-->Site Pages-->Selected Home.aspx --> then I clicked on "Info" button on the top right, looked at Manage Access and I validated the sharepoint group/user are in there.  I could also go to Site Permissions from the top right gear and validated to have the same settings.

Comment: I seem to have no luck finding the Page Permissions section. Unless I'm already hitting the right spot from what I have described. This modern UI really confuses me in location a lot of times. :-/

Answer (score 0):

By design, it is not "Page" ribbon in the modern page.

And check the new users permission in "/_layouts/15/user.aspx" page.

And Click "Share" button in the modern Home page to Share permission to the new users.